# Search by any character on a list of dict with Python

Tags: python

I want to search by any character on a list of dicts.

```
my_list = [
           {"name": "MrA", "age": 20, "height": 185},
           {"name": "MrsB", "age": 28, "height": 192},
           {"name": "MrC", "age": 18, "height": 170},
           {"name": "MrD", "age": 50, "height": 177},
           {"name": "MrsE", "age": 32, "height": 200},
           {"name": "Mrs18F", "age": 21, "height": 175}
          ]

keywords = "MrA"
my_list  = [item for item in my_list if keywords in list(item.values())]
print(my_list) # result is [{"name": "MrA", "age": 20, "height": 185}]
```

As seen, I can only search by full characters. But I want to handle this list with the expected result is which is search by any character on all fields:

With `keywords = "Mrs"`:

```
[{"name": "MrsB", "age": 28, "height": 192},
 {"name": "MrsE", "age": 32, "height": 200},
 {"name": "Mrs18F", "age": 21, "height": 175}]
```

OR `keywords = 18`:

```
[{"name": "MrA", "age": 20, "height": 185},
 {"name": "MrC", "age": 18, "height": 170}
 {"name": "Mrs18F", "age": 21, "height": 175}]
```

I don't know How do I make it right. Is there any way I can get the expected result?

Comment: why output of `keywords = 18` have two items?

Comment: So you want to search in all fields?

Comment: @I'mahdi Because "height": 185 and it will search by, all values

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check if the keyword is in [***`any`***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the values of each dictionary. This will be done by converting the keyword to a string, and each of the values:

```
def find(term, l):
    term = str(term)
    return [d for d in l if any(term in str(v) for v in d.values())]

print(find("Mrs", my_list))
print(find(18, my_list))
```

This gives:

```
[{'name': 'MrsB', 'age': 28, 'height': 192}, {'name': 'MrsE', 'age': 32, 'height': 200}, {'name': 'Mrs18F', 'age': 21, 'height': 175}]
[{'name': 'MrA', 'age': 20, 'height': 185}, {'name': 'MrC', 'age': 18, 'height': 170}, {'name': 'Mrs18F', 'age': 21, 'height': 175}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
my_list = [
    {"name": "MrA", "age": 20, "height": 185},
    {"name": "MrsB", "age": 28, "height": 192},
    {"name": "MrC", "age": 18, "height": 170},
    {"name": "MrD", "age": 50, "height": 177},
    {"name": "MrsE", "age": 32, "height": 200},
    {"name": "Mrs18F", "age": 21, "height": 175}
]


def match_keywords(it, keys):
    for val in it.values():
        if any(key in str(val) for key in keys):
            return True
    return False

keywords = ["Mrs", "MrD"]
my_list = [item for item in my_list if match_keywords(item, keywords)]
print(my_list)
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'MrsB', 'age': 28, 'height': 192}, {'name': 'MrD', 'age': 50, 'height': 177}, {'name': 'MrsE', 'age': 32, 'height': 200}, {'name': 'Mrs18F', 'age': 21, 'height': 175}]
```

Another example:

```
keywords = ["18"]
my_list = [item for item in my_list if match_keywords(item, keywords)]
print(my_list)
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'MrA', 'age': 20, 'height': 185}, {'name': 'MrC', 'age': 18, 'height': 170}, {'name': 'Mrs18F', 'age': 21, 'height': 175}]
```

This solution allows you to search by different keys across all values of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the keyword and the values to a string and then check if the value contains the keyword, something like this:

```
def search_by_value(search_list, keyword):
    result = []
    keyword = str(keyword)
    for l in search_list:
        for k, v in l.items():
            if keyword in str(v):
                result.append(l)
                break
    return result

my_list  =  [
              {"name": "MrA", "age": 20, "height": 185},
              {"name": "MrsB", "age": 28, "height": 192},
              {"name": "MrC", "age": 18, "height": 170},
              {"name": "MrD", "age": 50, "height": 177},
              {"name": "MrsE", "age": 32, "height": 200}
            ]

print(search_by_value(my_list, "Mrs"))
print(search_by_value(my_list, 18))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'MrsB', 'age': 28, 'height': 192}, {'name': 'MrsE', 'age': 32, 'height': 200}]
[{'name': 'MrA', 'age': 20, 'height': 185}, {'name': 'MrC', 'age': 18, 'height': 170}]
```

Comment: You never use `k`...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, Some values are `int` so you can check with `str(query)` and `str(value)`.

```
def fnd_query(lst, query):
    res = []
    for dct in lst:
        for val in dct.values():
            if str(query) in str(val):
                res.append(dct)
                break
    return res

print(fnd_query(my_list, 18))
print(fnd_query(my_list, 'Mrs'))
```

---

```
[{'name': 'MrA', 'age': 20, 'height': 185}, {'name': 'MrC', 'age': 18, 'height': 170}, {'name': 'Mrs18F', 'age': 21, 'height': 175}]

[{'name': 'MrsB', 'age': 28, 'height': 192}, {'name': 'MrsE', 'age': 32, 'height': 200}, {'name': 'Mrs18F', 'age': 21, 'height': 175}]
```